# REST API: cannot create widget

Tags: rest, echosign

On this page https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#WidgetFileInfo i'm trying to create widget (POST /widgets).
Here is `WidgetCreationRequest` exmaples and responses from server.

```
{"widgetCreationInfo":{"name":"SomeRandom","signatureFlow":"SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED","fileInfos":[{"documentURL":{"name":"83011.pdf","url":"http:\/\/www.state.gov\/documents\/organization\/83011.pdf","mimeType":"application\/pdf"}}]}}
```

Server is thinking (1-2 minutes) and gives "BAD_REQUEST" response.

```
{"widgetCreationInfo":{"formFieldLayerTemplates":[{"documentURL":{"name":"83011.pdf","url":"http:\/\/www.state.gov\/documents\/organization\/83011.pdf","mimeType":"application\/pdf"}}],"name":"SomeRandom","signatureFlow":"SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED","fileInfos":[{"documentURL":{"name":"83011.pdf","url":"http:\/\/www.state.gov\/documents\/organization\/83011.pdf","mimeType":"application\/pdf"}}]}}
```

I don't know why i decided to use formFieldLayerTemplates, but this time server says `You cannot work on behalf of this user`.

Document was randomly taken from google.
Please help me to create a widget, I despaired!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first request is absolutely correct. There seems to be some issue specific to the URL. I just tried it with the following public URL: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Donald_Specht/publication/220360902_Probabilistic_Neural_Networks._Neural_Networks_3109-118/links/0c96051b63d9acfb5e000000.pdf and it worked fine. Can you please try out at your end?

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have already tried using another url and succeed. So trouble was in the URL.